# System.Diagnostics.Process calling FFMPEG fails with international character

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ffmpeg

I'm using `System.Diagnostics.Process` to launch FFMPEG, and it works as intended on paths that only contain non-special characters.

```
string strParam = "C:\myFolder\foo.png";

Process ffmpeg = new Process();

ffmpeg.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
ffmpeg.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

ffmpeg.StartInfo.FileName = Path_FFMPEG;
ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments = strParam;

ffmpeg.Start();

ffmpeg.WaitForExit();
```

The above example works perfectly, but if I use "c:\myFolder\føø.png" I get the following error message:

> Could find no file with path 'C.\myFolder\f├©├©.png'

This looks like some kind of encoding error, but that's where my ideas stop.

Comment: How certain are you that the problem is invoking FFMPEG rather than getting the text to start with? Where are you getting the string from, and how are you diagnosing that it's correct?

Comment: I'm reading the file system using DirectoryInfo.GetFiles() on my local file system, and if I write that to console directly, the file name has the correct character. This also appears correctly if I step through with the debugger, all the way up to the actual process call.

Comment: Right. Is there any way of telling FFMPEG to read options from a file rather than as command line arguments?